# Mysql PHP to JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, graph

I have a php code returning this data from mysql [8,430], [8,430], [8,380], [8,380], [8,430]

Want to insert it in to this JavaScript data array, cant figure it out how.

```html
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('tankStatus.db.numbers.hostedresource.com', 'username', 'password')
   or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     
mysql_select_db('tankStatus') or die('Could not select database');
  
$dataArray=array();
$dateArray=array();
$in=0;
//get data from database
$sql="SELECT * FROM Additives ";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
if ($result) {
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $dataArray[$in]=$row["Calcium"];
      $dateArray[$in]=$row["pH"];
  $in++;
  }
  $arrayLenght = count($dataArray);
  for($x = 0; $x < $arrayLenght; $x++) {
  echo "{$dateArray[$x]},";
 echo "{$dataArray[$x]}";
  if($x < $arrayLenght-1){
  echo ", ";
  }
  }
}
?>will return 8,400, 8,420, 8,430, 8,430, 8,380, 8,380, 8,430
```

```html
// Graph Data ##############################################
 var graphData = [{
   // Visits
   data: [php data inserted here],
   color: '#71c73e'
  }, {
   // Returning Visits
   data: [ [6, 500], [7, 600], [8, 550], [9, 600], [10, 800], [11, 900], [12, 800], [13, 850], [14, 830], [15, 1000] ],
   color: '#77b7c5',
   points: { radius: 4, fillColor: '#77b7c5' }
  }
 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

**It's best to use JSON to get data from PHP to JavaScript:**

PHP: (get_data.php)

```
$formatted_data = array();
foreach($dataArray as $in => $ph){
    $formatted_data[] = array($in, $ph);
}

echo(json_encode($formatted_data)); exit();
```

JavaScript and jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: get_data.php,
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: json return testdata = {"18":"400","17":"420","16":"430","15":"430","12":"380","13":"380","14":"430"};

Comment: The code works with format like this testdata= [[6, 700], [7, 400], [8, 850], [9, 550], [10, 300], [11, 800], [12, 300], [13, 950], [14, 810], [15, 1500]];

Answer (score 0):

Either luck of experience or just don't get it but I couldn't use your answer.
Added the mysql php code to my main page and formatted the variable as the graph expected.

```html
//part of php mysql
    if ($result) {
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $dataArray[$in]=$row["Calcium"];
          $dateArray[$in]=$row["pH"];
      $in++;
      }
//end

//part og graph javascript
 graphData = <?php echo "[ "; $arrayLenght = count($dataArray);
  for($x = 0; $x < $arrayLenght; $x++) {
  echo "[{$dateArray[$x]},";
 echo "{$dataArray[$x]}]";
  if($x < $arrayLenght-1){
  echo ", ";
  }
  }
   echo " ]";
 ?>;
//end

//result
graphData = [ [8,400], [7,420], [7,430], [8,430], [8,380], [8,380], [8,430] ];
//end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you want your end result data to be an array of arrays. So I would suggest formatting your result as such where you parse your query result:

```
$array_of_arrays = []; 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $array_of_arrays[$in++] = [$row["pH"], $row["Calcium"]];
}
```

You may then echo the JSON encoded array of arrays into your JavaScript:

```
data: <?php echo json_encode($array_of_arrays); ?>,
```